# Adding a scrollbar in a div in sencha touch

Tags: sencha-touch

I want to add a scroll bar in div in sencha, I tried to do it CSS property overflow-y:scroll. Its showing the scroll bar but  scroll bar is disable. Its showing scroll bar when list is puhed up or down through touch. but its not visible all the times. Is there any other way to make scroll bar visible all the time?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this css to the div with the scrollbar

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 12px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); 
    border-radius: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
}
```